# How to compare my Date time Picker to my pc's current date in C#?

Tags: datetimepicker

Can't Compare my DateTimePicker to today's date subtracted by 18 years to the day.

I started with an if statement and didn't get far so I tried to use a method using conversions of the Picker and then compare but that didn't work either so I went back to the simple stuff.

(I do know that the compare is currently set to less then but I am trying to subtract 18 years to the day after I check that the picker was changed)

```
//First check if the datetimepicker was changed

if (dateTimePicker.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
  {
        //Second I am trying to figure out how to subtract the date by 18 years so that I can use that result to tell if it goes on with the code.
  }
```

So say the person puts in may 10th 1985, and today's date is june 8th 2019.
It will return that you are of age and so on with the code.
and if the person puts in may 10th 2010, it will return that you are too young and it will not continue with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectedDate = dateTimePicker.Value.Date;
var eligbleDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).Date; //subtract years to get eligble date
if (selectedDate <= eligbleDate ) {
     ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!